# Dual or triple (or even multiple) comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Almighty Gurus,
Please tell me, I want to know can comparison sm. set of variables in row, like this:

```
x < y >= z
```

or i need to do it in two steps?

```
(x < y) && (y >= z)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Javascript, you must do this type of comparison in two steps.

Python is the only widely used language I'm aware of that allows the first form (please comment if I'm incorrect).

Comment: Mathematica also allows the chained form.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `0 < -0.75 && -0.75 < 1`.

Because using `a < b < c` is like doing `(a < b) < c`.

Let explain your case:

- `0 < -0.75 < 1`
- the first comparison (`0 < -0.75`) is processed, which returns
- `false < 1`
- then false is converted to number 0
- `0 < 1` which finally returns
- true

Answer (score 1):

You can only do the latter in Javascript:

```
(x < y) && (y >= z)
```